# Markdown and Google Prettify

Tags: 7, input-formats

I have been working on a site, that allows users to submit encryption algorithms, for other users to test and/or crack them.

The problem I am having is in the text editor that I want to use to do this with.
Being that I am now very used to, and comfortable with the Stack Exchange Markdown, I wanted to make my site use the same thing.

What I tried, was downloading the [Markdown filter](http://drupal.org/project/markdown) module, along with the [Markdown Editor for BUEditor](http://drupal.org/project/markdowneditor) and [Google Code Prettify](http://drupal.org/project/prettify) modules.

I have been playing around with it for a little while, trying to configure it, and I noticed that there are several problems, that I can't figure out how to solve.

1. Block quotes don't work: When attempting to make a block quote, instead of making it correctly, it just looks like `> this is pseudo block quote text`.
   Is there a library that I need to / can install to get this to work?
2. Google prettify is working, but not coloring the code.
   Basically, I can get prettify to make the code look like this:

   ```
   public static void main (String[] args) {  
     System.out.println("this is a test example");  
   }
   ```

   It is not highlighted.

   ```
   public static void main (String[] args) {
     System.out.println("this is a test example");
   }
   ```

What am I doing wrong? Is this just a simple css issue? Is it something bigger? Should I use a different module entirely, and if so, which one? (I am using omega as my default theme. You can see an example of this that I created for debugging purposes [here](http://crackmycode2.nebulaprodev.com/questions/6/d).)

<sup><sub>(Note: This is not a question about a module bug, I am wondering if there is something that I have forgotten to set up, or am doing wrong, not the module itself.)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm getting a 403 forbidden on your [prettify.js](http://crackmycode2.nebulaprodev.com/sites/all/libraries/prettify/src/prettify.js). If you change the permissions of the `sites/all/libraries/prettify/src` folder to 777, It should solve your problem.

Comment: I changed the permissions for now, you should be able to look at the file

Comment: It seems to work right now?!

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. In setting the permissions 777, that doing so is what solved the problem. I guess drupal was unable to read the file with the current permissions. I think you just solved my problem by accident! :D Although, can you figure out why the block quotes on markdown aren't working